# Account Financial Report Webkit Module not working on Odoo Apps Store

Tags: pdf, webkit, report, odoo, openerp-7

I have tried to download the Account financial report webkit module for OpenERP 7.0.

Account Financial Report Webkit module download and install successfully in my local system in my fresh new addons for OpenERP 7.0.

I have downloaded that module in below URL

[Click to download Account Financial Report Module from Odoo Apps Store](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/7.0/account_financial_report_webkit/)

I got in stuck while i am printing the General Ledger report PDF Format

I got the Below Traceback while I am printing the report.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/custom_addons/account_financial_report_webkit/report/webkit_parser_header_fix.py", line 252, in create_single_pdf
    **parser_instance.localcontext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 302, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "memory:0x9cb385ecL", line 22, in render_body
    <%
TypeError: translate_call() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

2015-10-29 07:17:06,249 15317 ERROR dynaweld_15_09_15 openerp.service.web_services: Exception: (u'Webkit render', u'\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/custom_addons/account_financial_report_webkit/report/webkit_parser_header_fix.py", line 252, in create_single_pdf\n    **parser_instance.localcontext)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 302, in render\n    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render\n    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context\n    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template\n    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "memory:0x9cb385ecL", line 22, in render_body\n    <%\nTypeError: translate_call() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 712, in go
    (result, format) = obj.create(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 353, in create
    result = self.create_source_pdf(cursor, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/server/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 513, in create_source_pdf
    return self.create_single_pdf(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/custom_addons/account_financial_report_webkit/report/webkit_parser_header_fix.py", line 257, in create_single_pdf
    raise except_osv(_('Webkit render'), msg)
except_osv: (u'Webkit render', u'\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/custom_addons/account_financial_report_webkit/report/webkit_parser_header_fix.py", line 252, in create_single_pdf\n    **parser_instance.localcontext)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 302, in render\n    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render\n    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context\n    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template\n    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "memory:0x9cb385ecL", line 22, in render_body\n    <%\nTypeError: translate_call() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)\n')
2015-10-29 07:17:06,367 15317 ERROR dynaweld_15_09_15 openerp.netsvc: Webkit render
```

Can any one help me to how can i fix my issue for above traceback.

Comment: Did you made any customization on this report ? if yes the show us. From where translate_call() method calling.

Comment: Not yet but i have fixed it from my side but i have no time to post my answer but finally thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the file addons/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py and restart openerp. That might fix the issue.

Comment: This is not the right way for this solution .. u can try from your self in your local system then after u can told me.